# What does 今日の所は良いでしょう mean here?

Tags: words, meaning, usage

```
これも全て先生のおかげですね。感謝するんですよ？

は、はい 本当に、感謝しています

突っ込むべき時に突っ込むべき場所にきちんと突っ込めない男はもてませんよ？

まあ、今日の所は良いでしょう。皆にも伝えないといけませんからね。仲間たちにも順番に顔を出すように伝えて下さいませ
```

In this I'm not sure what she would be referring to. Would someone say something like the above in the situation where they are saying "that's enough chitchat/etc for today(as we can do it tomorrow or whenever)" to bring the conversation to an end, or is it referring directly to what was said in the previous line?

Comment: It's like "so much for today".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

今日の所は良いでしょう。 is roughly equivalent to "That's it for today." The sentence is used by a teacher or a boss and that means the speaker has finished speaking, lesson or anything else he/she want, and the listener(s) can leave now.